# Rally Custom Grid Parent of Parent Tag Features

Tags: parent-child, rally

I'm trying to create a custom grid in Rally to filter Tasks on the tags of both the task parent and/or the parent of the parent. I'm able to get the parent's tag, but not the syntax of the parent of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you'll have a hard time doing this with the custom grid app.  The problem is that the WorkProduct field that represents the Task's parent is of type Artifact since it can be either a story or a defect.  But Artifact doesn't have a Parent field.

It should be possible to write an app to do this though, by querying from the other direction- find features with a specific tag and load their children, find stories with a specific tag, and then load all of the children tasks associated with those stories...